# DrayTek Single Static IP routing

Tags: linux-networking, static-ip, draytek

This is the current configuration of our DrayTek Vigor 2925:

- dynamic IP configured on WAN1
- WAN1 feeds LAN1 which is connected to a switch.
- LAN2 is currently connected to a Linux server.

ISP gave a single static IP (NOT A BLOCK), gateway, subnet, and DNS IPs.

I would like to route traffic of static IP to and from the server on LAN2.

I have spoke with DrayTek's support and so far either I am not understanding or they aren't. They sent documentation links that I had already read and tried. Each one was dealing with a block of IPs and use DHCP in the LAN configuration. DHCP can be disabled but I'm unsure about what to put for the DNS, IP, and subnet. And whether to use "For NAT Usage" or "For Routing Usage" on LAN2.

There is also an option of using "IP Routed Subnet" that can be matched to a MAC or LAN port in the LAN settings. But this uses DHCP and does not appear to allow disabling.

And then there are VLANs in LAN setting which don't appear to have any correlation to the "Multi-VLAN" settings in WAN.

My questions:

1. Do I have to change WAN1 to the static IP or can it be left as dynamic?
2. Should I be using "Multi-VLAN" to setup the static IP and then route it to LAN2?
3. Is there any setup on the Linux box that has to happen?
4. Am I thinking/going about this all wrong?

Any help or suggestion would be great. Thank you.